# Symfony2 - Upgrade to 3.0

Tags: symfony

How could I upgrade my Symfony2 2.8 project to 3.0?
I changed sf version to 3.0 in composer and started a command like in this [article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/upgrade/major_version.html#upgrade-major-symfony-composer)

```
-sh-4.1$ composer update symfony/symfony Loading composer repositories with package information Updating dependencies (including require-dev) Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - sensio/generator-bundle v2.5.3 requires symfony/framework-bundle ~2.2 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.8.0], symfony/framework-bundle[v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6, v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21, v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.3, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32, v2.3.33, v2.3.34, v2.3.35, v2.3.4, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.8.0].
    - sensio/generator-bundle v2.5.3 requires symfony/console ~2.5 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.8.0], symfony/console[v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.8.0].
    - sensio/generator-bundle v2.5.3 requires symfony/framework-bundle ~2.2 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.8.0], symfony/framework-bundle[v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6, v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21, v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.3, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32, v2.3.33, v2.3.34, v2.3.35, v2.3.4, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.2, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.8.0].
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/console v2.5.0
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/console v2.5.1
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/console v2.5.10
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/console v2.5.11
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/console v2.5.12
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/console v2.5.2
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/console v2.5.3
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/console v2.5.4
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/console v2.5.5
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/console v2.5.6
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/console v2.5.7
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/console v2.5.8
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/console v2.5.9
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/console v2.6.0
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/console v2.6.1
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/console v2.6.10
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/console v2.6.11
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/console v2.6.12
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/console v2.6.2
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/console v2.6.3
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/console v2.6.4
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/console v2.6.5
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/console v2.6.6
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/console v2.6.7
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/console v2.6.8
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/console v2.6.9
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/console v2.7.0
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/console v2.7.1
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/console v2.7.2
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/console v2.7.3
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/console v2.7.4
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/console v2.7.5
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/console v2.7.6
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/console v2.7.7
    - don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0|don't install symfony/console v2.8.0
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v3.0.0, v2.8.0].
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.13|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.14|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.15|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.16|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.17|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.18|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.19|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.20|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.21|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.22|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.23|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.24|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.25|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.26|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.27|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.28|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.29|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.30|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.31|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.32|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.33|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.34|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.35|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.3.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.4.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.5.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.8|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.6.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.2|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.3|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.4|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.5|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.6|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.7|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.8.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.0
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony 3.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.0.0].
    - Installation request for sensio/generator-bundle == 2.5.3.0 -> satisfiable by sensio/generator-bundle[v2.5.3].
```

Here is the require block from my composer.json:

```
    "require": {
            "php": ">=5.3.9",
            "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
            "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
            "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
            "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
            "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
            "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
            "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~4.0",
            "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
            "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
            "white-october/pagerfanta-bundle": "^1.0"
        },
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many of your dependencies are not correct. You should have a look there: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/v3.0.0/composer.json

The `sensio/distribution-bundle` should be at version `~5.0` for instance.

Answer (score 1):

I have written an extensive step-by-step guide at http://manuel.kiessling.net/2015/12/07/upgrading-a-symfony-project-from-2-6-to-3-0/.

The way I've approached upgrading (from Symfony 2.6 to 3.0, in my case) was as follows:

- **Create an empty Symfony 3.0 project from scratch.** It's thrown away afterwards, but it's really helpful for comparing what has changed between both versions.
- **Change the project structure.** Symfony 3.0 introduces a new file/directory structure, and I've moved things around accordingly (I git moved `app/console` to `bin/console`, and then copied the `bin/console` script from the Symfony 3.0 project folder to `bin/console` in actual project. Then, I moved `app/SymfonyRequirements.php` to `var/SymfonyRequirements.php`, and moved `app/cache` and `app/logs` to `var/`. )
- **Fix the code.** At this point, the project did not work anymore, and what followed was the grunt work of changing the code. You can see all changes that had to be made in [this side-by-side diff](https://github.com/journeymonitor/control/compare/64c9f63...5be5f63?diff=split&name=5be5f63).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should watch your dependencies requirements. It seems to be wrong versions.